# Selecting Specific Match from Existing Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a block of text that includes a series of dollar values. The goal is to pull out the third dollar value every time. Example text is as follows.

```
Bunch of text blah blah blah
Ctr Pty ID: 1 $4,233.65 $5,073.64 $9,307.29 $9,273.41 $0.00 $0.00 $33.88
```

I have come up with the following code that matches all values after the dollar sign, but I have not found a way to pull out the third value:

```
(?<=Ctr Pty ID.*\$)\S+
```

Results:

```
4,233.65 5,073.64 9,307.29 9,273.41 0.00 0.00 33.88
```

I am expecting to pull out the 3rd dollar value which in this case would be 9,307.29

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Using a quantifier in the lookbehind, perhaps like `(?<=Ctr Pty ID:(?:[^$]*\$){3})\S+` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbCtr+Pty+ID%3a+%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%24%5d*%5c%24%29%7b3%7d%28%5cS%2b%29&i=Bunch+of+text+blah+blah+blah+Ctr+Pty+ID%3a+1+%244%2c233.65+%245%2c073.64+%249%2c307.29+%249%2c273.41+%240.00+%240.00+%2433.88) but you might also use a capturing group `Ctr Pty ID: (?:[^$]*\$){3}(\S+)`  See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Csl1s1/1)

Comment: @accdias I am trying to write the code for UiPath which utilizes vb. net to ultimatley write a statement like: system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str_PDFText,"(?<=Ctr Pty ID.*\$)\S+").ToString

Comment: @Thefourthbird, the first solution you gave worked! Is that essentially not capturing the next three dollar signs after the word "Ctr Pty ID" then slecting all values past that until the next white space?

Comment: @RobertSchauer Yes that is the approach. It is a broad match and does not take the formats of the dollar values into account.

Comment: If you want to take the current values of the dollar sign into account you might also use`(?<=Ctr Pty ID:[^$]*(?:\$\d+,\d+\.\d+ ){2}\$)\d+,\d+\.\d+`  [Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCtr+Pty+ID%3a%5b%5e%24%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%24%5cd%2b%2c%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b+%29%7b2%7d%5c%24%29%5cd%2b%2c%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b&i=Bunch+of+text+blah+blah+blah+Ctr+Pty+ID%3a+1+%244%2c233.65+%245%2c073.64+%249%2c307.29+%249%2c273.41+%240.00+%240.00+%2433.88)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the match only and use a quantifier in the lookbehind, one option could be assert what is on the left is `Ctr Pty ID:` followed by 3 times any char except a `$` and then match a `$`

After that, match 1+ times a non whitespace char.

```
(?<=Ctr Pty ID:(?:[^$]+\$){3})\S+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCtr+Pty+ID%3a%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%24%5d*%5c%24%29%7b3%7d%29%5cS%2b&i=Bunch+of+text+blah+blah+blah+Ctr+Pty+ID%3a+1+%244%2c233.65+%245%2c073.64+%249%2c307.29+%249%2c273.41+%240.00+%240.00+%2433.88)

To get a more specific match taking the current format of the dollar into account (with comma and dot) you might use

```
(?<=Ctr Pty ID:[^$]*(?:\$[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2} ){2}\$)[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCtr+Pty+ID%3a%5b%5e%24%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%24%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d%29*%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d+%29%7b2%7d%5c%24%29%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%28%3f%3a%2c%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d%29*%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d&i=Bunch+of+text+blah+blah+blah+Ctr+Pty+ID%3a+1+%244%2c233.65+%245%2c073.64+%249%2c307.29+%249%2c273.41+%240.00+%240.00+%2433.88)